# Does the Galois group of a Pisot polynomial contain the alternating group?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $p(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a monic polynomial of degree $n$. Suppose that exactly one complex root of $p$ is of modulus $> 1$, and that the remaining $n-1$ roots of $p$ belong to the open unit disk in the complex plane (such a polynomial is necessarily irreducible, and is sometimes called a Pisot polynomial).

> Is $\mathrm{Gal}(p(X)/\mathbb{Q}) \in \{A_n,S_n\}$ ?

Pisot polynomials are quite common, for instance Perron has shown that if $p(X) = X^n + a_{n-1}X^{n-1} + \dots + a_1X + a_0$ and $|a_{n-1}| > 1 + a_0 + a_1 + \dots + a_{n-2}$ then $p(X)$ is a Pisot polynomial.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

David Speyer has beaten me to it, but for what it's worth, a simple explicit example is
$$p(X)=X^4-2X^3-5X^2-4X-1$$
which is a Pisot polynomial, and has Galois group the dihedral group of order 8.

How did I find it? I started from observing that if $\vartheta$ is the positive root of $X^2-X-1$, then $\alpha=1+\sqrt{\vartheta}$ is an algebraic unit with only one conjugate inside the closed unit disk, and thus $-1/\alpha$ is a Pisot-Vijayaraghavan number, with this minimal polynomial.

**Addendum:**  The Pisot polynomial

$$p(X)=X^4-2X^3+X-1$$

again has dihedral Galois group of order 8, corresponding to another quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\vartheta)$, and produces a root less than $2$ (which also happens to be the fourth smallest limit point of the set of PV numbers).  This number is mentioned on page 1251 of David W. Boyd, [*Pisot and Salem numbers in intervals of the real line*](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1978-32-144/S0025-5718-1978-0491587-8/S0025-5718-1978-0491587-8.pdf), Math. Comp. **32** (1978), 1244-1260.

Comment: Great! What is the smallest such Pisot number you can find (for this example it is about $3.5$)? Can you find a pisot number $\leq 2$ with Galois group not in $\{S_n, A_n\}$.

Comment: @Pablo: I've edited one in. When you bound the size of the number *and* the degree, you'll be left with a finite set of polynomials, so you can (at least in principle) enumerate them all and check their Galois groups in turn.

Comment: This is fantastic! And one last thing: Is there an example with a polynomial satisfying the inequality on its coefficients stated in the question?

Comment: Ok, I have found one myself: $X^6+26X^5+X+1$.

Answer (score 18):

Any number field $K$ which has a real place is generated by a root of a Pisot polynomial. So the answer is no. For example, we can take $p$ a prime $\geq 11$, and use the real subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$, to get a Pisot polynomial whose splitting field is cyclic of degree $(p-1)/2$.

Suppose $K$ has $r$ real places, and $2s$ complex places. Let $V_i$ be $\mathbb{R}$ for $1 \leq i \leq r$, and be $\mathbb{C}$ for $r+1 \leq i \leq r+s$, and let $\sigma_i : K \to V_i$ be the $r+s$ embeddings of $K$. Then recall that
$$\bigoplus \sigma_i : K \to \bigoplus V_i$$
embeds $\mathcal{O}_K$ as a discrete full rank lattice in $\bigoplus V_i$. Projecting further onto $\bigoplus_{i \neq 1} V_i$, we get a dense additive subgroup of $\bigoplus_{i \neq 1} V_i$. In particular, there is some nonzero $\theta \in \mathcal{O}_K$ such that $|\sigma_i(\theta)|<1$ for all $i \neq 1$. And, the norm of any algebraic integer is at least $1$, we have $|\sigma_1(\theta)|>1$.